# Poisson GLM for non-integer counts - R

Tags: r, glm, poisson

I was hoping to get some advice on a GLM with Poisson family.

I have a data set with the number of bites taken by each individual over a period of time. As the individuals observed were feeding for different periods of time, when I calculated the bite rate for each individual as bites/minute, I have ended up with non-integer numbers. Now, based on what I have read so far, I should still be able to do a GLM with a Poisson family. However, I am encountering errors and I think this may be because R is not liking the fact I'm using non-integers. Does anyone have any advice?

```
Example <- structure(list(Species = c("Fish1", "Fish2", "Fish3", "Fish4", 
"Fish5", "Fish6", "Fish7", "Fish1", "Fish2", "Fish3", "Fish4", 
"Fish5", "Fish6", "Fish7", "Fish1", "Fish2", "Fish3", "Fish4", 
"Fish5", "Fish6", "Fish7"), Site = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Bite_Rate = c(3.5, 7.5, 
0, 0, 2.45, 5.5, 6.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.03, 32.1, 15.6, 18.2, 19.1, 
20.5, 20.5, 3.5, 5.7, 6.7, 23.2, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L), spec = structure(list(
   cols = list(Species = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
   "collector")), Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
   "collector")), Bite_Rate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
   "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
   "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))

str(Example) # check structure 
Example$Species<-as.factor(Example$Species) # set species as a factor 
str(Example) # check structure 
glm<-glm(Species~Bite_Rate, data=Example, family = poisson) # create the GLM
```

The error message when I run the GLM is:

```
Error in if (any(y < 0)) stop("negative values not allowed for the 'Poisson' family") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(y, 0) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
```

I don't actually have any negative values which is what throws me off a little bit.
Any advice would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
Based on the comments, I have updated my example data so that it has counts of bites and the time of observation in seconds

```
Example <- structure(list(Species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Fish1", 
"Fish2", "Fish3", "Fish4", "Fish5", "Fish6", "Fish7"), class = "factor"), 
    Site = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Bites = c(0, 10, 18, 17, 6, 0, 1, 0, 19, 
    12, 7, 3, 5, 1, 5, 0, 10, 18, 17, 7, 25), Observed_Seconds = c(50, 
    33, 47, 20, 17, 10, 14, 21, 48, 10, 50, 33, 47, 20, 17, 10, 
    14, 21, 48, 10, 90)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Species = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Bites = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Observed_Seconds = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Karolina. You need to use an offet, can you add to the data.frame the numbers used to calculate the rate, that is the minutes and the bites (integers). And your glm is specified wrongly. Ok I write an example below, if you can, update your dataset and this helps you solve your problem quickly

Comment: I was looking at the regression. Is this your actual data? The offset below is the way to do the regression. The variance is much more than a poisson. Depending on what you want to know from the model, you might need to account for this kind of extra variance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the seconds (denominator) with which you normalized, and the actual bites (counts).

Next include the minutes as an offset, and note, your response variable is on the left hand side of ~ :

```
fit = glm(Bites ~ Species,offset=log(Observed_Seconds),
family=poisson,data=Example)
```

You can look at the summary:

```
summary(fit)

   Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
SpeciesFish1  -2.8679     0.4472  -6.413 1.42e-10 ***
SpeciesFish2  -1.1436     0.1857  -6.158 7.35e-10 ***
SpeciesFish3  -0.5738     0.1581  -3.629 0.000284 ***
SpeciesFish4  -0.7732     0.1543  -5.011 5.42e-07 ***
SpeciesFish5  -1.3269     0.1961  -6.766 1.33e-11 ***
SpeciesFish6  -1.7198     0.2887  -5.958 2.56e-09 ***
SpeciesFish7  -1.5244     0.1925  -7.921 2.35e-15 ***
```

Seems very significant, but ne good thing to check is whether the data is overdispersed, and also include other factors (e.g Site):

```
fit_quasi = glm(Bites ~ Species + factor(Site),offset=log(Observed_Seconds),
          family=quasipoisson,data=Example)
summary(fit_quasi)

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)    -2.9754     1.0713  -2.777   0.0167 *
SpeciesFish2    1.8487     1.1434   1.617   0.1319  
SpeciesFish3    2.2731     1.1152   2.038   0.0642 .
SpeciesFish4    2.1246     1.1205   1.896   0.0823 .
SpeciesFish5    1.3533     1.1604   1.166   0.2662  
SpeciesFish6    1.2754     1.2658   1.008   0.3336  
SpeciesFish7    0.8922     1.1719   0.761   0.4612  
factor(Site)2  -0.2325     0.5132  -0.453   0.6587  
factor(Site)3   0.6118     0.4677   1.308   0.2154  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 5.521045)
```

If it follows a poisson, the dispersion will be around 1, but in this case, it is overdispersed.

Comment: Ah thank you! I just edited my data based on your first comment. Thank you, I will give this a go now!

Comment: thanks! It worked but... it turns out my model is really overdispersed…. Residual deviance:  663.22  on 119  degrees of freedom. Would this approach still be appropriate for a quasipoisson model?

Comment: Yeah. I was about to say that. You need a quasipoisson. For the above code, just use family= quasipoisson, and include the site as a factor too.

Comment: Ah thank you! If I'm adding site as a factor, would that be as an interaction term? Or just Bites ~ Species ~ Site?

Comment: I did it! Thanks for your help! Just one more question... with a regular GLM I would normally run Tukey comparisons after. Can I do that too with this model? The code I normally use is something like this: library(multcomp)
TUKEY<-(glht(MODEL, mcp(Species="Tukey")))
summary(TUKEY)… Also, as I have now added an additional factor does that make it a mixed effect model?

Comment: Yeah you can use glht, thats a good package. This is still a glm, so it applies. Your Site is a fixed effect, there are no random effects (you need to use another package like lme4 or glmmTMB), so this is 100% fixed effects

Comment: This is a really good and comprehensive answer. Strong job, @StupidWolf !

Comment: Thanks @Georgery! Just trying my best :)